# Set the onTouchListener on a background

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to set an onTouchListener on the background which was set by writing `android:background="@drawable/xxx"` in my `.xml` file? Maybe I can set one to my `RelativeLayout` which has this `drawable` as a background? If not, what is the easiest way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: whats that??? You have to set onTouch to Relative-layout which has the background..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set onTouchListener to your Relative layout.Then calculate

```
 onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
//then use ev.getX() and ev.getY() to get x an y coordinate on which section touch is happend.

  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to send intent with x and y coordinates in it, and display these coordinates in another activity. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`OnTouchListener` can be set to a `View`. Fortunately, `RelativeLayout` is a `View`. So here's the solution:

```
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener());
```